# How do I extract info from crunchbase

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel, copy-paste

I need to go to this webpage

https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/paypal

And then copy/paste data (such as headquarters, description and website) into my excel file. My macro is doing all the work, but the  getelementsbytagname does not seem to work... I guess it has something to do with the list structure () Any clues on that?

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value=InternetExplorer.HTMLDocument.getElementsByTagName("definition-list container")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a class name to the getElementsByTagName method.
Try passing tagname such as "div" or "li" or use the
GetElementById method and pass an element id.

e.g.:

```
 ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(2,1).Value=InternetExplorer.HTMLDocument.getElementById("info-card-overview-content")
```

By the way, crunchbase has an API that could be useful for what you are trying to acomplish:

> http://data.crunchbase.com/v3/docs

:).